# Sharepoint 2013 Approval Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I'm trying to create a SP Approval workflow in a document library that automatically runs when users publish a document.  I'm having trouble setting the approvers to a value in the document's column.

For instance my document library has a column called Approver.  I want the workflow to automatically set that as the approver for the workflow.

Currently i can set the approver to the right a column but then I can't set the workflow to automatically run when the user publishes a major version.

I can also do the opposite where it runs automatically when the user publishes a major version but it won't automatically set the approver.

Any help in this are will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: would be wiser to attach some screenshot of your library including the workflow where we can see what exactly you mean :) By the way, I assume your workflow settings are set to `Start when items are created: YES` and `Start when items are modified: YES` if it applies.

Comment: HI.  I only want the workflow to start when the user publishes a major version.  The library has one custom content type that includes a column for an approver.